# SQL use the elements of an array as foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if SQL or MySQL has the option to use array elements as foreign keys. Something like this, however, doesn't work.

```sql
ids TEXT[],
FOREIGN KEY(ids) REFERENCES table(ids)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL, array type `TEXT[]` does not seem to work with MySQL

Comment: I'm using MySQL, perhaps that syntax is incorrect as well.

Comment: Then it is even uglier, you will store data as text separated by `,`. I suggest to normalize schema.

Comment: @DSchana . . . The question is "obviously not" because MySQL does not support arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short and correct answer: normalize schema!

---

Ugly workaround using generated column(assuming that array has maximum number of elements known in advance):

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT,
 ids TEXT[],
 id_rel_1 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ids[1]::int) STORED,
 id_rel_2 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ids[2]::int) STORED,
 id_rel_3 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ids[3]::int) STORED,
 id_rel_4 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ids[4]::int) STORED,
 id_rel_5 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ids[5]::int) STORED,
 FOREIGN KEY(id_rel_1) REFERENCES ch(id),
 FOREIGN KEY(id_rel_2) REFERENCES ch(id),
 FOREIGN KEY(id_rel_3) REFERENCES ch(id),
 FOREIGN KEY(id_rel_4) REFERENCES ch(id),
 FOREIGN KEY(id_rel_5) REFERENCES ch(id)
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d2bc99284055a6a3a9b031c460cd8b90)**